# Solving recurrence without using Master Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

> Let $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2}) + n^2$. Solve for $T(n)$ without using Master Theorem.

**My try:** I used substitution and got $$T(n) = 3^kT(\frac{n}{2^k}) + \sum_{l = 0}^{k-1} (\frac{3}{4})^ln^2$$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. What's the next step? Maybe geometric series is helpful. The answer should be $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Change variables: $n = 2^k$, $k = \log_2 n$; $t(k) = T(2^k)$. You get:

$\begin{align*}
  t(k) 
     &= 3 t(k - 1) + 2^{2 k} \\
  \frac{t(k)}{3^k} - \frac{t(k - 1)}{3^{k - 1}}
     &= \frac{2^k}{3^k} \\
  \frac{t(k)}{3^k}
     &= 3^k
         \cdot \sum_{1 \le r \le k}
                 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^r
         + \frac{t(0)}{3^0} \\
  t(k)
     &= 3^k \cdot \left(
                     \sum_{1 \le r \le k} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^r
                       + t(0)
                   \right)
\end{align*}$

The sum inside parenteses converges when $k \to \infty$ (to 3), so this is bounded by $t(0) \le \text{sum} \le 3 + t(0)$:

$\begin{align*}
  T(n)
     &= \Theta(3^{\log_2 n}) \\
     &= \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})
\end{align*}$

The last one by:

$\begin{align*}
  3^{\log_2 n}
    &= \left( 2^{\log_2 3} \right)^{\log_2 n} \\
    &= \left( 2^{\log_2 n} \right)^{\log_2 3} \\
    &= n^{\log_2 3}
\end{align*}$

($x^{\log y}$ is conmutative ;-)

Comment: I think the right expression is $$
  t(k) 
     = 3 t(k - 1) + 2^{2 k} \\
  \frac{t(k)}{3^k} - \frac{t(k - 1)}{3^{k - 1}}
     = \frac{2^{2 k}}{3^k} \\$$